# Why Xcode compile assets every time even I don't make any changes

Tags: xcode, xcasset

As title said, I'm using Xcode 12.1, Mbp 15' 2017. My project is a large one that have over 300 images or icons and it will take aboud 45s to compile the assets. I just rebuild it after a success building and it will recompile assets.

What should I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, every time when I run my project the Xcode recompiles Assets for about twenty seconds even when I don't change anything. I found that the reason is a assets file imported by Cocoapods.
When I run my project, the script named 'Copy Pods Resources' was run. In this script it changed the cache for assets.
So I move the assets file to my project, everything back to normal.
Hope can help you.